# Nav panel in Jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, panel

Hi I'm trying to implement a panel with 2 links.
My idea is to have 3 different files: page1.html and page2.html

Page1:

```
<div>
    <h1> This is the Page 1</h1>
</div>
```

Page2:

```
<div>
    <h1>This is the Page 2</h1>
</div>
```

In my main page (main.html) I want to place the panel and a Div where the different pages will be loaded.

Is there any way to implement like fragments in Android, or similar, I mean, declare the div:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

and when the users clicks on the links the content of the pages load in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Navbar` plugin:

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="page1.html">Page One</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html">Page Two</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
```

Please take a look to the [Docs](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html)